# How to make a whole <section> element's area clickable?

Tags: html, refactoring, semantics

I'm working with a codebase where there is a list of articles rendered inside a section element that is wrapped by a link, like this:

```
<a href="link/to/article">
    <section>
        <h2>Article title</h2>
        <img src="path/to/article/img">
        <p>Short description</p>
    </section>
</a>
```

The content inside the section tag is the title, the image and a short description. All the article previews are rendered like this in a tabular/grid-like layout. When a section is clicked, the whole contents of the article are rendered in a new page.

The reason for this is that the whole section area should be clickable. Since this markup doesn't seem too semantic for me, I was wondering if this code is correct, and if it is not, is there a better approach to make a whole section clickable?

Answer (score 7):

What you've done is fine and correct and works well. [The W3C even states](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables,
>   and so forth, **even entire sections**, so long as there is no interactive
>   content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

They include an example similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery as such to achieve that.....No need using the link tag

```html
 

  <section id="clickable_section">
    <h2>article title</h2>
    <img src="article/img">
    <p>Short description</p>
  </section>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickable_section").click(function() {
      //Do something....
    //Continue doing something,like redirecting the user to the new page

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Although is not a bad idea to use Javascript to catch the click event on an entire section, it should never replace one, at least, anchor element linking to the same target.

Answer (score -1):

Having an anchor work like that is pretty kludgey. Might be better to do something like this:

html:

```
<section data-link="https://www.google.com">
  <h2>article title</h2>
  <img src="path/to/article/img">
  <p>Short description</p>
</section>
```

css:

```
section {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

javascript (jQuery):

```
$('section').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href=$(this).data('link');
})
```

Comment: Not kludgey at all and allowed by the current HTML5 standard.